# Radiation levels per hour

Tags: radiation

I am trying to understand radiation levels. I have found that where I live the radiation levels go up to 100-120 nsv / hour. 
Does that mean that to find the daily radiation, I would need to multiply by 24, and if I want the yearly to then multiply by the number of days?

How much is considered as unsafe?

Comment: you might read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation  or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert   second link has some interesting info on dosages

Answer (score 3):

I can give you some rough ideas about danger levels:

- 500 rem = 5 Sv exposure over less than a month will produce life-threatening immune suppression by killing hematopoietic stem cells in the bone marrow.  Victims die of infection.
- 1000 rem = 10 Sv exposure over less than a week will produce life-threatening gastrointestinal problems by killing “crypt” cells in the lining of the intestine.  Victims die of electrolyte loss incident to diarrhea.
- 2000 man-rem = 20 man-Sv exposure (i.e., individual dose multiplied by number of people exposed) over many years will cause one fatal case of cancer.
- 50 rem = 0.5 Sv cumulative exposure is the legal limit for occupational exposure.

Your local dose rate of 120 nano-sieverts per hour (nSv/h) works out to 0.1 rem per year.  That’s less than the worldwide average of 0.3 rem/y and the U.S. average of 0.6 rem/y.  (We have more radon.)

By these estimates, the average U.S. resident gets a lifetime exposure of 40 rem, which implies an incremental 2% risk of fatal cancer.  This is a not-insignificant fraction of total cancer deaths, which amount to 20-25% of deaths from all causes.

Comment: There is some evidence that low levels of radiation are beneficial. This is called radiation hormesis. If radiation hormesis applies, then the OP should be concerned about the unusually low levels of radiation where she lives.

Comment: The legal limit is, of course, dependent on jurisdiction (though most developed countries use similar values), and many occupational setting have lower regulatory limits, and many regulated sites use still lower internal control values.

Comment: @BenCrowell - tenths of a microseivert an hour are unusually low? The range given by the OP just happens to be what the BBC is reporting as normal for the part of Russia near the recent rocket explosion (coincidence?).